# Browser not displaying spaces of list text within SELECT tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using IE7 and it seems to display options in my SELECT tag without the leading spaces in the text - the text seems to be trimmed. For example, in the HTML code block below, even though option 1 to 3 have three spaces in the front of its text, the browser when displaying them seems to perform a trim and displays it to the user without the leading spaces.

Code block 1:

```
<select size="3">
    <option value="1">   aaa</option>
    <option value="2">   bbb</option>
    <option value="3">   ccc</option>
    <option value="4">ddd</option>
    <option value="5">eee</option>
</select>
```

It also seems that when you access the option's text through JavaScript, the returned value is also trimmed.

Code block 2:

```
var value = list.options[i].text;
```

Is there a way to force the browser to display the spaces as well or is this something I am stuck with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces:

```
<select size="3">
    <option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aaa</option>
    <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;bbb</option>
    <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ccc</option>
    <option value="4">ddd</option>
    <option value="5">eee</option>
</select>
```

=== UPDATE ===
Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWhUH/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
&nbsp;
```

in lieu of a space?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but try having `&nbsp`; instead of just a space

Answer (score 0):

It's browser behavior, removing white space from the `option` text.. I found out that the `innerHTML` is "preserved" though, so you can keep the HTML intact with the ordinary spaces then just add this JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var dropDownLists = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropDownLists.length; i++) {
        var oDDL = dropDownLists[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < oDDL.options.length; j++) {
            oDDL.options[j].innerHTML = oDDL.options[j].innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
        }
    }
};
```

This will replace the space with its HTML entity for you.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/xu2nN/).

Comment: That "browser behaviour" is the [treatment of white space specified by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#whitespace): `In particular, user agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing output inter-word space...authors should not rely on user agents to render white space immediately after a start tag or immediately before an end tag`.